# How to get row id using color code in phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a excel file which contains certain rows with color i want to get the row id of a particular color code but unable to do it .. already searched but found nothing below is my code for [PHPEXCEL](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

```
$cellColor = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($cell->getCoordinate())->getFill()->getStartColor()->getRGB();
```

This will give me the color code and for the value i have `$cell->getValue()` where `$cell` is some variable for `$cellIterator`

```
  foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); 

           foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) 
            {
              $cellColor = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($cell->getCoordinate())->getFill()->getStartColor()->getRGB();

            if (!empty($cell->getCalculatedValue())) {
                   if ($cellColor == 'yellow') { 
                       echo ($cellColor.'======'.$cell->getValue());
                   }
               }
            }
   }
```

`$cell->getValue()` will give me the value of that particular color code 
But, the problem is if i have 2 rows with color yellow then `$cell->getValue()` will give two value like 
 `0-> yellow1` 
 `1-> yellow2` 
but after deleting the 1st yellow colour data in excel then result will be 
`0-> yellow2` 
which is wrong what i need is 
`0->''`
 `1-> yellow2` 
Thats why i need row id for that particular color so that i can identify the row.

Comment: Did you try $cell->getRow()???  @rocky

Comment: Yes already tried that it will return the row id but the problem i am facing is that the iteration to get the color code is on each celli. i want to get the color code by visiting each row then i have to create a array of each colour code

Answer (score 0):

**After hours of practicing got my expected result**

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('someFile.xls');
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {

    //$worksheetTitle = $worksheet->getTitle();
    $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
    $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    //$nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;

    $groupCount = array();
    $standardSetCount = array();
    $standardCount = array();
    $learningTargetCount = array();

    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
        for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
            $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
            $colorCode = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($cell->getCoordinate())->getFill()->getStartColor()->getRGB();

            /*
             * Yellow 
             */

            if ($colorCode == 'FFFF00') {
                $val = $cell->getValue();
                //$dataType = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::dataTypeForValue($val);
                $groupCount[] = $val;   // $groupCount[] = $dataType;
            }

            /*
             * gold
             */

            if ($colorCode == 'CC9900') {
                $val = $cell->getValue();
                $standardSetCount[] = $val;
            }

            /*
             * red
             */

            if ($colorCode == 'FF3333') {
                $val = $cell->getValue();
                $standardCount[] = $val;
            }

            /*
             * green
             */

            if ($colorCode == '00CC33') {
                $val = $cell->getValue();
                $learningTargetCount[] = $val;
            }
        }
    }

    $group = (array_chunk($groupCount, $highestColumnIndex));
    $standardSet = (array_chunk($standardSetCount, $highestColumnIndex));
    $standard = (array_chunk($standardCount, $highestColumnIndex));
    $learningTarget = (array_chunk($learningTargetCount, $highestColumnIndex));

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($learningTarget);
}
```